# How to I register FluentValidation validators in external assemblies when using Nancy and .Net Core?

Tags: .net-core, nancy, fluentvalidation

I am using Nancy.Validation.FluentValidation (v2.0.0), but I am unable to register IValidator classes in my DI container (I am using Autofac), apparently because they are in an external assembly.

[According to the documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Nancy-and-Validation), you used to have to call `AppDomainAssemblyTypeScanner.LoadAssemblies` to explicitly scan those assemblies, but this class no longer exists. How should validators now be registered?

I am using NancyFX v2.0.0-clinteastwood and .Net Core v2.1.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I have to be more specific with my DI registrations for the validator within Nancy than I had to be with Web Api. I have to register the specific validators such as

```
builder.RegisterType<MyTypeValidator>().As<IValidator<MyType>>();
```

whereas with Web Api I didn't have to be so specific. I am using the decorator pattern, and with Autofac and Web Api I could register the decorator via

```
builder.RegisterType<MyTypeHandler>()
                                .Named<IHandler<MyType, IEnumerable<ReturnType>>>("handler");

containerBuilder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof(ValidationDecorator<,>),
                                                      typeof(MyTypeHandler<,>),
                                                      fromKey: "handler");
```

without need to register the individual validators.